# Define a Topographic EEG/MEG plot function using Julia

Tags: julia, julia-plots, makie.jl

Is it possible to define a function like [plot_topography](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72729-topographic-eeg-meg-plot) in MatLab to draw the Topographic EEG/MEG plot in Julia?[image]

Comment: The MATLAB link has a second link to the source code. This includes 3D contour plotting of the data on a drawing of the head including drawing of nose and ears. A port of the MATLAB or similar code to a Julia plotting package is certainly something that could be done if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following image is what I have achieved with the code posted [here](https://github.com/likanzhan/PlotTopography.jl/blob/main/src/PlotTopography.jl).

[image: Julia rewritten version]